# tfe_variable JSON to HCL support

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

I'm hitting `Error: Incorrect attribute value type` when passing `var_3` below to a `tfe_variable` of type HCL.
Is there a way to convert the decoded JSON variable to HCL?

My `config.json`:

```json
{
    "vars": {
        "var_1": "foo",
        "var_2": "bar",
        "var_3": {
            "default": "foo"
        }
    }
}
```

My terraform config:

```
variable "tfe_token" {}

provider "tfe" {
  hostname = "app.terraform.io"
  token    = var.tfe_token
}

data "tfe_workspace" "this" {
  name         = "my-workspace-name"
  organization = "my-org-name"
}

locals {
  json_config = jsondecode(file("config.json"))
}

resource "tfe_variable" "workspace" {
  for_each = local.json_config.vars

  workspace_id = data.tfe_workspace.this.id
  key          = each.key
  value        = each.value
  category     = "terraform"
  hcl          = true
  sensitive    = false
}
```

Comment: Doublechecking the documentation, it appears for your situation you may want to try setting the value for the `hcl` argument to `false`.

Comment: right. I was hoping to use hcl. Wanted to avoid jsonencoding the value as type string